# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket error - Reasons of this failure?

Tags: 14.04, mysql

This is my first post here. I am a newbie in Ubuntu servers :)

I've a WordPress multi-site running on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server, and about once per month all the sites are down due to some MySQL issues:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket error
```

1. Why does it happen?
2. How can avoid this error?
3. How can I detect this error without browsing manually any of my WordPress sites?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to "localhost" the socket connector is used, but when you connect to "127.0.0.1" the TCP/IP connector is used.

You could try using "127.0.0.1" if the socket connector is not enabled/working.

Also try to enable the socket again by:

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock

sudo service mysqld restart
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to restart mysql again (using "sudo start mysql"). But I want to avoid this happening again because in some weeks it'll happen again... I guess.

Comment: You are welcome, you'll be fine as you don't miss with the sock files

Comment: Then.. why this error happened to me this morning? Why did it happen last month? and the previous month? I want to know the reasons and the answers to my 3 questions. Then I'll check the answer ;)

Comment: I cant answer you for what something related to your system